# The conjunction "Because"

Tags: grammaticality

Can we use the conjunction "because" more than once? Example: He cried because he was scolded by his father because he did not tell his real marks.

Comment: Hi @Gramfused, Welcome to English Language and Usage. ELU prefers questions which demonstrate some modicum of research. Please cite any source(s) you've explored thus far in search of an answer. _Thanks!_

Comment: @freeling10 Seriously, what "source(s)" would you expect a low-rep user to explore here?

Comment: @deadrat, Um, I didn't suggest a visit to the Library of Congress. What about Google it first, see what comes up? Or visit a couple of grammar-related sites (maybe to no avail, but _make the effort_) and include that info in the question. Not that challenging, even for "low-rep user(s)."

Comment: @freeling10 Google, you say. Sure, what could go wrong? Let's google *because*. Oops 3.5B hits. Let's try *because multiple*. Better: 47.5M hits. How about *because multiple grammar*. Now we're getting somewhere, under 1M hits. Did you think my answer was reasonable? What search terms do you figure I used? For a delightful and informative read go here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/9800/125330. See if you figure out which tribes you and the OP belong to.

Comment: @deadrat, You're being deliberately obtuse. What you've done above (searching Google several different ways) is _exactly_ what OP should have done. Adding info akin to, "I've Googled it and can't figure out the answer—or how to correctly word the search terms," is evidence of _research_. Even if it's just a quick Google search which unfortunately dead-ends, it provides context. (Besides, I'm sure that a majority of Google's **because** search results were for sites containing **subordinating conjunction porn**, thus easily discounted.)

Comment: It's grammatical but stylistically queriable. It is possible that the addition of any further _because_'s would result in an unacceptably convoluted sentence. Simplification by dividing into simpler sentences would be the solution.

Comment: @freeling10 Instead of answering my questions, you decided to speculate on my interiority. Wonderful. So your stated position is that *the google didn't help* provides evidence of research and context and that "dead-ends" advance the discussion of such questions. I'm going to do you the courtesy of not pretending that you believe that and renew my request: please tell me what search terms you would have used to research the question. (**subordinating conjunction porn** -- that's not a thing.)

Comment: @deadrat, Hm, hadn't really thought about it like that. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2):

Language nests, recursively, and so such things will always be possible, however awkward they may sound.

He cried because he was scolded and he was scolded because he lied. So he cried because he was scolded because he lied.

People will figure it out. They may not like it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question, and the answer depends on important parsing rules in English grammar. First, let's note that adverbial adjuncts (like clauses of reason) have freedom of place in sentences, more than do objects and complements. Thus we may say

> **[1a]** Because I cut my hand, I cried

and look forward to the verb modified by the introductory subordinate clause

or we may say

> **[1b]** I cried because I cut my hand.

and look backward for a suitable verb to be modified by the trailing subordinate clause.

In [1a] and [1b], there is only one candidate, namely the verb *cried*. But when there is more than one possible candidate, we look for semantic cues to choose between them, and we may find ambiguity. Take the sentence

> **[2]** I cried because I cut my hand because I was careless

This could mean that there were two reasons for tears -- the pain of the cut and my frustration over my carelessness. I'll represent the parse as

> **[2a]** I cried<sub>1,2</sub> {because I cut my hand}<sub>1</sub> [and] {because  I was careless}<sub>2</sub>

Or the sentence could mean that there is only one reason for tears -- the pain of a cut made through carelessness. Presumably, it would have hurt just as much if I'd cut myself through a deliberate miscalculation, but it wouldn't have been an occasion for tears. I'll represent this parse<sup>*</sup> as

> **[2b]** I cried<sub>2</sub> {because I cut<sub>1</sub> my hand {because I was careless}<sub>1</sub>}<sub>2</sub>

(The nested braces in [2b] represent the recursive nature of the parse, as noted by tchrist in his answer.)

The answer to your question is yes, we can use *because* in this way, i.e., it's grammatical. But stylistic courtesy demands that we not burden our readers with pondering which parse to make.

---

*The subscripts on a verb match the subscripts on the brace-enclosed clauses that modify said verb.

Comment: The discourteous driveby downvoter has struck again. Is the answer wrong or misleading? Then you've deprived the OP of a properly corrected response. Is the answer right? Then you've misled the OP about the answer. I renew my lament that this site puts up with this plague upon it.